# Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that there exists integers $x$ and $y$ with $x^2 + 1 = py$ and if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime. Show that there exists integers $x$ and $y$ with $x^2 + 1 = py$ and if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Don't know where to start. Please help! All I know is that Wilson's theorem and Fermat's could possibly help. Don't know what the $y$ does/how it relates to the problem.

Comment: Check p=2, x=3, y= 5.

Comment: @gnasher729 $p$ is assumed to be odd. Otherwise this is indeed false, as you point out.

Comment: The duplicate uses Wilson and little Fermat, which you were supposed to use here, as you indicated. Next time you should try to search for it before saying "Don't know".

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of Euler's criterion. If $p$ is an odd prime and $a$ is a number coprime with $p$, then
\begin{equation}
a^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}\equiv
\begin{cases}
1 & \quad \text{if there exists an integer } x \text{ such that } x^2\equiv a \mod p \\
-1 & \quad \text{if there is no such integer}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Two elementary proofs of this can be found on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion

Let us apply this with $a=p-1$, which is obviously coprime with $p$.

If $p=4k+1$, then $(p-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}=(p-1)^{2k}\equiv (-1)^{2k}\equiv 1\mod p$, so by Euler's criterion, there exists some integer $x$ such that $x^2\equiv p-1\mod p$, meaning that $x^2+1=py$ for some integer $y$.

If $p=4k+3$, then $(p-1)^{\tfrac{p-1}{2}}=(p-1)^{2k+1} \equiv (-1)^{2k+1} \equiv -1\mod p$, so by Euler's criterion, there can exist no integer $x$ such that $x^2+1\equiv 0\mod p$.